# Convert CURL command line to PHP

Tags: php, parsing, curl, command-line, converters

How can I convert to PHP Curl?

```
curl -X GET \<br>
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APPIDKEY" \<br>
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: RESTAPIKEY" \<br>
-G \<br>
data-urlencode 'where={"playerName":"Sean Plott"' \<br>
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/ClassName<br>
```

I have tried:

```
$ch = curl_init();<br>
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/ClassName");<br>
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');<br>
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Parse-Application-Id: APPIDKEY","X-Parse-    REST-API-Key: RESTAPIKEY"));<br>
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);<br>
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'where={"playerName":"Sean Plott"}');<br>
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);<br>
$player = curl_exec($ch);<br>
curl_close($ch);<br>
var_dump($player);
```

but the result is:**bool(false)**!

Comment: @ValentinRusk It's not an exact duplicate, but similar.

Comment: before you call `curl_close`, call `var_dump` on `curl_getinfo()`.
Post the result into your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also remove the `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` and `CURLOPT_POST`, `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` and append the data passed in postfields to `CURLOPT_URL`.
TRY THIS CODE.

```
$data = 'where={"playerName":"Sean Plott"}';
$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/ClassName';
$requestUrl = $url . '?' . url_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $requestUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
  array(
    "X-Parse-Application-Id: APPIDKEY",
    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: RESTAPIKEY"
  )
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$player = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($player);
```

HTH,

VR

Comment: Thak you!!! It is working now!